# Positioning Error

Tags: android, android-studio, indoor-positioning-system

I want to track user inside university class. So i decided using indoorAtlas.

I have already upload my floor plan. So the next step is to calibrate and positioning using IndoorAtlas app. But when i choose the venue and floor i have received this error "No Network connections. Please connect to a wifi network or enable mobile data on your device."

I have 2 venue. Both of them i already test to positioning but the result is same. My connection is ok. I already used mobile data and wifi but still got nothing.
Can you help me ?

Comment: Post your code and specify where in the code that error occurs

Comment: There seems be some bug with the MapCreator app as it wrongly reports this error. Try a few times again or just dismiss the error dialog. I got it working even with that message.

Comment: @leonard febrianto I am trying to use canvas for drawing circle for positing but have no luck any help would be appreciated.

Comment: give me your question link

Comment: here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31691539/positing-in-android-using-indooratlas